# managed_file FormElement submitting form upon file upload

Tags: views, 8, theming, forms, ajax

How do i prevent managed_file(Browse Button) from calling submitForm function upon uploading file?
I've added

```
 '#attributes' => [
  'submit' => FALSE,
  'onclick' => 'return false'
]
```

to no avail.

This is the UI.

[image]

Upon uploading file

[image]

managed_file and submit code below -

```
    $form['fileUpload'] = [
    '#type' => 'managed_file',
    '#upload_location' =>  Settings::get('bulk_imsi_excel_upload', '0'),
    '#multiple' => FALSE,
    '#upload_validators' => [
      'file_validate_extensions' => array('xls')
    ],
    '#attributes' => [
      'submit' => FALSE,
      'onclick' => 'return false'
    ]
];

$form['submit'] = [
    '#type' => 'submit',
    '#value' => $this->t('Submit'),
    '#attributes' => [
      'class' => ['use-ajax-submit'],
      'style' => 'color:white;'
    ],
    '#ajax' => [
      'callback' => '::submitForm',
      'event' => 'click',
      'progress' => [
        'type' => 'throbber',
        'message' => 'sending request'
      ]
    ]
  ];
```

Comment: the managed file add a submit function in the method processManagedFile (
https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21file%21src%21Element%21ManagedFile.php/class/ManagedFile/8.2.x ). You can remove it with a form_alter.

Comment: I strongly recommend against this (trying to force Drupal to do something other than what it does) and figure out how to solve your problem the Drupal way (working with Drupal the way it does what it does). The path you are on will only lead to unintended consequences and further troubles down the line.